# AJAX/Jquery - Remove form.onSubmit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So i want to run ajax when the user inputs 4 characters and not when the user clicks/pushes the submit button, so i'd have to remove this line:

```
form.on('submit', function(e){
```

But in that case i would get an error. My code:

```
       $('#passwordField').keyup(function () {
            if (this.value.length == 4) {


                $(function(){
                    var form = $('#login-form');

                        if(form.is('.loading, .loggedIn')){
                            return false;
                        }

                        var user = form.find('#usernameField').val(),
                            messageHolder = form.find('#usernameErrorContainer');
                        var pass = form.find('#passwordField').val(),
                            messageHolder = form.find('#passErrorContainer');

                        e.preventDefault();

                        $.post(this.action, {user: user}, function(m){

                            if(m.error){
                                form.addClass('error');
                                messageHolder.text(m.message);
                            }
                            else{
                                form.removeClass('error').addClass('loggedIn');
                                messageHolder.text(m.message);
                            }
                        });
                        $.post(this.action, {pass: pass}, function(p){

                            if(m.error){
                                form.addClass('error');
                                messageHolder.text(p.message);
                            }
                            else{
                                form.removeClass('error').addClass('loggedIn');
                                messageHolder.text(p.message);
                            }
                        });

                    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
                        form.addClass('loading');
                    });

                    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
                        form.removeClass('loading');
                    });
                });


            }
        });
      }
  });
      })
```

For this app i don't need any security measurements, so don't offer me to read articles about security please.

Edit: the actual form:

```
  <form id="login-form" name="login-form" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="usernameField" name="username" maxlength="4" placeholder="username">
    <input type="password" id="passwordField" maxlength="4" name="password" placeholder="password">
    <span id="usernameErrorContainer"></span>
      <span id="passErrorContainer"></span>

  </form>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @CodeGodie, i get an error which says that i have to declare e function first

Comment: `this.action` is looking for the form's action attribute, but `this` is not the actual form.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined, you got that other error because you don't have the actual form, so let me update the post

Comment: thats because `e.preventDefault();` is located inside `$(function () {}` place it outside of it

Comment: Yes you do. When you run `e.preventDefault` it assumes `e` is a function

Comment: ok now that helped, but i still get e as undefined

Comment: Why are you using this code if you have no idea how it works? `m` is whats returned from your AJAX call.

Comment: I'm using it because i need to make a simple ajax call to get an account, also the only thing i asked was how to remove e function without breaking my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you changed your `form.submit` to the `keyup` you forgot to change other elements as well. For example, 
            you still have `e.preventDefault` inside your anonymous function, which will throw an error since `e` is not within the function,
             to fix it place the `e.preventDefault` outside of the anonymous function or remove it sinces its not doing anything. Also
            all your `form` variables are assuming you are using variable created by pure JS but you are actually creating it using jquery like this: `var form = $('#login-form');` you
             need to change it to this: `var form = document.getElementById("login-form");`